# Download zip file in web view in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to download file from a web view. I have used javascript inject to click on submit button.

I'm specifically trying this for offline aadhaar - https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offline-kyc

Reference Code -

```
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: "https://resident.uidai.gov.in/offline-kyc" }}
                ref={webviewRef}
                renderLoading={LoadingIndicatorView}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                injectedJavaScript={runFirst}
                onMessage={onMessage}
                renderError={loadError}
                // onFileDownload={({ nativeEvent: { downloadUrl } }) => {
                //     console.log(downloadUrl);
                //   }}
            />
```

I have tried with api request by creating/replicating the browser behaviour for api call but it's not working. Any suggestions.

Comment: The website is not reachable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

You can use [downloadFile](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#downloadfileoptions-downloadfileoptions--jobid-number-promise-promisedownloadresult-) API to download and save the file to the device.